# Understanding procs in ruby

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, proc

I'm puzzled over the following code:

```
Proc.new do |a|
    a.something "test"

    puts a.something
    puts "hello"
end
```

It doesn't throw any errors when it runs. However nothing is printed for either `puts` statement. I'm curious about the `a.something` "assignment". Perhaps this is a method call w/ parens omitted. **What is happening in the above code?**

Comment: That code doesn't do anything, except for creating a closure that is never run.

Comment: Are you actually running the `Proc`, or just declaring it?

Comment: It's being returned from a method (that I didn't write). More general ruby question: how does the `something` field on `a` in the above example work? Can fields just be declared on objects anytime in ruby?

Comment: @Sunday: `a.something` is a method that is called with a single argument in the first line of the block and without arguments in the third line.

Comment: You're just creating a Proc that is never called and doesn't even have a name.  Its the same thing as if you tried this:  String.new("hello").  That line creates a new string, but nothing is done with it.  You're doing this:  Proc.new({|a| ...})   Its just floating in space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Proc.new ...             # create a new proc

Proc.new{ |a| ... }      # a new proc that takes a single param and names it "a"

Proc.new do |a| ... end  # same thing, different syntax

Proc.new do |a|
  a.something "test"     # invoke "something" method on "a", passing a string
  puts a.something       # invoke the "something" method on "a" with no params
                         # and then output the result as a string (call to_s)
  puts "hello"           # output a string
end
```

Since the last expression in the proc is `puts`, which always returns `nil`, the return value of the proc *if it is ever invoked* will be `nil`.

```
irb(main):001:0> do_it = Proc.new{ |a| a.say_hi; 42 }
#=> #<Proc:0x2d756f0@(irb):1>

irb(main):002:0> class Person
irb(main):003:1>   def say_hi
irb(main):004:2>     puts "hi!"
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end

irb(main):007:0> bob = Person.new
#=> #<Person:0x2c1c168>

irb(main):008:0> do_it.call(bob)  # invoke the proc, passing in bob
hi!
#=> 42                            # return value of the proc is 42

irb(main):009:0> do_it[bob]       # alternative syntax for invocation
hi!
#=> 42
```

Comment: That's a great example, thanks. Interesting point about the return value (42 in your example).

Comment: @SundayMonday The 'return value' of any block (and method, and statement) is always the value of the last expression in the statement.

Comment: Yet another syntax to call a lamba/proc: `do_it.(bob)`.

Comment: @Phrogz Indeed. I just needed to make the connection.

Comment: @Phrogz Well, only if there isn't an early `return` statement, but I may be being a bit pedantic here.

Comment: @Andrew Pedantry is entirely appropriate when molding new programmers. Good warning.

Comment: @andrew or if `next` is called, to get more pedantic.